# asp classic setting session in session_onstart

Tags: session, asp-classic

I have the following excerpt from my global.asa that should set the session timeout to 900 minutes:

```
Sub Session_OnStart


Session.Timeout=900


End Sub
```

The sessions, I suspect based on user responses, aren't lasting 900 minutes. It would make more sense if the values are in seconds.

Is there an IIS (Windows 2000 server) setting I can check to see what's overriding what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh. Timeout worked just fine. The users were leaving their sessions open and coming back to them sometimes days later. Argh!!